# Docker login within docker:stable image container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Im trying to login to our docker trusted registry (dtr) within a docker:stable container and getting the below error.

```
> WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use
> --password-stdin. Warning: failed to get default registry endpoint from daemon (Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at
> unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?). Using
> system default: https://index.docker.io/v1/ Cannot connect to the
> Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon
> running?
```

Im able to run other docker commands such as docker --version within this container, but unable to run docker login. Im able to successfully login to our dtr outside of this container.

What im trying to do is create a customized version of the docker:stable image, where we have pulled down images from our dtr in order to make builds slightly quicker and not have to worry about pulling these down each time we build.

Is there an alternative to the above?

Im trying to do this all in a Dockerfile, and build the image from this.

> FROM docker:stable
>
> RUN apk update && apk upgrade && \
>       apk add --no-cache bash wget
>
> RUN docker --version
>
> RUN docker login dtrurl -u username -password

Comment: Why are you trying to use the `docker:stable` image?  Have you read all the caveats at https://hub.docker.com/_/docker/?

Answer (score -1):

try running that command like this

```
RUN sudo docker login dtrurl -u username -password
```